# Can you toggle readonly on a TinyMCE 4.x editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'd like to switch a form between enabled / disabled states.  The form includes a formatted text field implemented using a tinyMCE 4.0 editor.  I can set this to be readonly on load as follows

```js
tinyMCE.on('AddEditor', function(addEditorEvent) {
    addEditorEvent.editor.settings.readonly = true;
});
```

but subsequently calling

```js
tinyMCE.get('my-editor').settings.readonly = false;
```

has no effect.  Is there a way to trigger the editor to re-initialize or some other way of getting it to pick up this change in state?

Comment: Good solution scarba, i wasn't able to find it even in the website of tinymce (only found the one for tinymce 3.x.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`setMode`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setmode) method:

```
editor.setMode('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
  var is_disabled = false;
  function enable_disable(btn) {
      is_disabled = !is_disabled;
      tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', !is_disabled);
      btn.value = is_disabled ? "Enable" : "Disable";
  }
</script>
<textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Disable" onclick = "enable_disable(this)" />
```